# Responsive and unorganized CSS image grid

Tags: html, css, image

Any suggestions on how I can make a unorganized gallery grid like this one below?

I have tagged the photo bellow but I am limited to 6 pictures and no more ,
mostly want to make it responsive for any display size device and my pictures are in standard horizontal format.

[image: The example image unorganized grid]

I have tried fixing the positioning but my pictures are with rectangular shapesand I don`t know how to make them mask in a polygon shape

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Borders, pseudo elements, fixed (absolute) positioning and background images. I suspect making this responsive would be a nightmare unless you gracefully fall back to horizontal imaging.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -2):

Try `overflow:hidden;` ?

then set width and height fit the polygon box

Comment: Why he must use `overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: Would still make them rectangular.

Comment: because the pictures are rectangular but the box is polygon